# iOS writing to asset library observations

Tags: alasset

I am attempting to write an app that reads images from the asset library, modifies the image's GPS data and writes it back to the asset library. I store the assets in a mutableArray via the "enumerating assets" methods. Most of the details on how to do the various steps, I got from searching this forum. Thanks!

I have found that when I write the first "asset" via the "writeimagedatatosavedphotosalbum" method, all the elements of the mutableArray associated with the assets' URL became null. Furthermore, I noticed that writing back an image does not replace the original image, but instead creates a second instance of the image.

Just thought I'd pass these results along, in case others had questions. And, of course, I'd be interested in other's comments, observations, etc.

This forum has provided me with great information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your **ALAsset** object is only as good for the amount of time that your **ALAssetsLibrary** object is around.  You either need to do everything you want in the completion block when you get the **ALAsset**, or store the **ALAssetsLibrary** in an instance variable so [ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) does not deallocate it.

Answer (score 0):

An **ALAsset** is essentially a Core Data object who can have properties accessed from multiple threads but a **NSManagedObject** or a subclass of **NSManagedObject** does not make sense without a parent **NSManagedObjectContext** much in the same way an ALAsset doesn't make sense without an **ALAssetsLibrary**.

It is common practice to store the **NSManagedObjectContext** on the *AppDelegate*; and while I abstract that functionality into a wrapper/singleton there is a retained reference to the **NSManagedObjectContext** throughout the app lifecycle. Apply the same logic to the **ALAssetsLibrary** and everything will works as expected.